# Update object in memory with values from req.Body

Tags: go

I am creating a simple in-memory server before doing things with a database. I have this update method:

```
type Nearby struct {
    ID          int   `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Me          int   `json:"me,omitempty"`
    You         int   `json:"you,omitempty"`
    ContactTime int64 `json:"contactTime,omitempty"`
}

    func (h NearbyHandler) updateById(v NearbyInjection) http.HandlerFunc {
        return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            params := mux.Vars(r)
            decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
            var t Nearby
            err := decoder.Decode(&t)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            mtx.Lock()
            item, ok := v.Nearby[params["id"]]
            mtx.Unlock()

            if !ok {
                panic(errors.New("No item to update"))
            }

            // !! Ok, how can I overwrite the properties from t onto item

            if ok {
                json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(item)
            } else {
                io.WriteString(w, "null")
            }
        }
    }
```

I am looking to take the key/values from t, and write them onto the item object. `t` gets decoded into a struct value (I assume), and item is a struct value found in a map. Both `item` and `t` have the same type (`Nearby`)

In JavaScript, all I am looking to do would be:

```
Object.assign(item, t);
```

Just trying to accomplish something similar with Go.

With Golang, I can do this:

```
    item.ContactTime = t.ContactTime
```

but I only want to overwrite `item.ContactTime` if `t.ContactTime` is defined.

Comment: You want to write all *non-empty* properties from `t` to `item`? If that's the case then passing `0`(empty value for int) in `t.Me` could not be handled properly?

Comment: Re: `You want to write all non-empty properties from t to item`, yes I suppose so. But I don't understand your second question.

Comment: I updated the OP with a parallel from JavaScript.

Comment: It's possible that instead of using a struct for Nearby, it could be a Map. That might make it easier to manipulate the object in the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Just overwrite the item in your map:

```
v.Nearby[params["id"]] = t
```

Comment: `t` is not complete, it might be missing fields, the `item` that already exists in the map is more complete and I need to mix the values of item with t and then put the result in the map

Comment: You will have to loop all old values, save the non-empty ones, loop all new values and the the empty ones with the old values. Theres no equivalent function in golang.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use https://github.com/imdario/mergo function `Merge`. I don't think there is any reason to reinvent the wheel in this one and go's lack of generics does not help with such operations. [example:](https://github.com/imdario/mergo#nice-example)

```
src := Foo{
    A: "one",
    B: 2,
}
dest := Foo{
    A: "two",
}
mergo.Merge(&dest, src)
fmt.Println(dest)
// Will print
// {two 2}
```

I also think you should make all `Nearby`'s properties pointers so that you can always compare them against nil to make sure they were not set.